# scrapy crawl category tree

Tags: python, scrapy

I am a newbie in python so please have patience
I need to crawl a website (online shop) in order to obtain the category tree, that would imply navigating in a tree of pages, and also keeping the parents of the current sub-sub-...-category in order to generate a clean category structure.
So please just picture how an online store would keep record of it's product categories

Basically I need to obtain items with comma separated strings with *tree nodes* like bellow:

```
MainCateg1
MainCateg1, MainCateg1Sub1
MainCateg1, MainCateg1Sub1, MainCateg1Sub1Sub1
MainCateg1, MainCateg1Sub1, MainCateg1Sub1Sub1, MainCateg1Sub1Sub1Sub1
MainCateg1, MainCateg1Sub1, MainCateg1Sub1Sub1, MainCateg1Sub1Sub1Sub2
...
MainCateg1, MainCateg1Sub2, 
MainCateg1, MainCateg1Sub2, MainCateg1Sub1Sub1, MainCateg1Sub1Sub1Sub1
...
MainCateg2
MainCateg2, MainCateg2Sub1
MainCateg2, MainCateg2Sub1, MainCateg2Sub1Sub1
MainCateg2, MainCateg2Sub1, MainCateg2Sub1Sub1, MainCateg2Sub1Sub1Sub1
...
and so on...
```

The number of subcategory levels is variable and unknown.
I don't know how to approach this because it would seem I would have to call a script recursively while keeping record of previous levels in the actual order of appearance.
I can get the categories from a menu that is a ul with

> id="cat"

and respective subcategories from a div with

> class="block-layered-content"

So my script so far looks like this:

```
import logging
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider 
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector 
from products.items import Categories
import urlparse 
from scrapy.http.request import Request

class CategoriesSpider(BaseSpider): 
    name = "categories" 
    allowed_domains = ["myshop.com"] 
    start_urls = ['http://www.myshop.com/']

    def parse(self,response): 
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response) 
        listings = hxs.select('//ul[@id="cat"]/li') 
        links = []
        #scrap listings page to get listing links
        for listing in listings: 
            link=listing.select('.//a/@href').extract()[0] 

        #parse listing url to get content of the listing page

        for link in links: 
            item=Categories() 
            item['link']=link 
            yield Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url, link), meta={'item':item},callback=self.parse_listing_page)

        #get next button link 
        next_page = hxs.select('//a/@href/text()').extract()[0]

        if next_page: 
            yield Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url, next_page), self.parse)

    #scrap listing page to get content 
    def parse_listing_page(self,response): 
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response) 
        listings = hxs.select('//div[@class="block-layered-content"]/ul/li') 
        item = response.request.meta['item'] 
        logging.log(logging.WARNING, response)
        yield item
```

But obviously it's wrong.
What I do so far is parse the main categories on the main page, and for each of them, I access the category page and try to get the content (subcategories) found there. But considering there is an unknown number of subcategories, 
I cannot write 10-15 sub-parsers... because first: a category might have just one subcategory, while another category might have 15 sub-sub-categories. 
Plus I need to be able to store the curent "branch" (Maincat->SubCat1->SubSubcat1->...) and only return that.

So how can I adapt this script to my needs?

Comment: what about calling `parse` again instead of `parse_listing_page`?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any of the xpaths from your question in the myshop.com site unfortunately. However, I think you can restructure your project to achieve the results you want. I would suggest having just one parse routine since each page can have links and needs to be scraped for its categories. You need the following sections in the parse routine:

Extract the category for this page. Add the category to the existing meta data and yield the meta data.

```
category = response.xpath( extract the category )
if response.meta['breadcrumbs']:
    breadcrumbs = response.meta['breadcrumbs'] + ', ' + category
else:
    breadcrumbs = category
item['breadcrumbs'] = breadcrumbs
.... extract anything else
yield item
```

Extract the forward links from the page and submit a request to queue them for parsing and pass on the meta data.

```
links = response.xpath( extract the links )
for link in links:
    yield Request(link, meta={'breadcrumbs': breadcrumbs})
```